# Pegar valor de variável externa e jogar em um input

Tags: php

Tenho um upload de imagens, que possui uma variável chamada `$nome_atual`, onde fica gravado o caminho do arquivo.

Preciso pegar esse valor e jogar num `input`, em uma outra página. É possível?

PARTE DO ARQUIVO UPLOAD.PHP

```
 /* se enviar a foto, insere o nome da foto no banco de dados */
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$pasta.$nome_atual)){
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO fotos (foto) VALUES (".$nome_atual.")");
                echo "<img src='fotos/".$nome_atual."' id='previsualizar' class='img-responsive'>"; //imprime a foto na tela
                echo "'http://audiosonic.com.br/novo/fotos/".$nome_atual."'";
            }else{
                echo "Falha ao enviar";
            }
        }else{
            echo "A imagem deve ser de no máximo 1MB";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Somente são aceitos arquivos do tipo Imagem";
    }
}else{
    echo "Selecione uma imagem";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Você pode obter esse valor na outra página de diversas maneiras. A mais simples, é usando get, mas você também pode usar post, sessions, cookies e o que mais sua criatividade permitir.

Comment: Algum exemplo prático? Sou iniciante, estou tendo dificuldades em fazer.

Comment: Você só precisar pegar o valor, ou também enviar o arquivo dessa outra página?

Comment: A outra pagina no caso seria essa? `/novo/fotos/`

Comment: Esse upload faz o carregamento da imagem e já mostra a visualização da mesma. A outra página, digo principal, é um formulário de cadastro. A pessoa que se cadastra tem que enviar um documento comprobatório, por isso o upload. Foi a forma mais interessante que achei pra fazer. O arquivo em questão é o upload.php, e existe um outro, matricula.php, que tem um campo que precisa ser preenchido com o caminho da imagem, antes de salvar no banco.

Comment: Mas como essa página upload.php está sendo chamada? Dependendo de como você está chamando ela, os métodos para obter o valor podem mudar. Session não é a maneira mais "bonita" de se fazer isso. Se ainda assim quiser, é só você dar um session_start() no início das páginas que vão usar as sessões, e depois definir uma variável de sessão como faz com outras variáveis. $_SESSION['imageUrl'] = 'blábláblá' e depois chamar ela na página matricula.php, já que ela é tipo uma variável super global, com algumas diferenças importantes. Vale a pena pesquisar sobre.

Comment: `<form id="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="3-upload.php">
                        <input type="file" id="imagem" name="imagem" /> <br>
                    </form>
                    <div id="visualizar"></div>`

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira, não estou muito preocupado com a beleza, porque estou muito atrasado nisso. Vou pesquisar sobre o que falou, obrigado. Se puder me direcionar melhor sobre o assunto, serei muito grato! Obrigado pelo seu tempo!

Comment: Na verdade, eu deveria ter colocado o upload de imagem no mesmo cadastro que estou fazendo, 1 coisa só, não teria problemas... mas, ainda estou fazendo mais algumas coisas, não vou poder mudar tudo, do zero... por isso, acho que uma solução, mesmo que seja na "gambiarra", seja a melhor para o momento.

Comment: @Everson, preciso pegar o caminho completo da imagem, para jogar em um outro formulário, que vai para o banco de dados, não importa a forma, só preciso que ele conste no novo formulário, para realizar o cadastro completo.

Comment: @Francisco, as páginas são as seguintes: `matricula.php`, que contém o formulário e `upload.php`, que faz o envio da imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Como o autor da pergunta disse que não está com tempo para explorar e a maneira mais correta, quer algo simples e não deu informações suficientes para uma resposta melhor, vou dar uma solução generica.

Embora essa solução não vá trazer nenhum risco de segurança ou desempenho a sua aplicação, **não recomendo** que utilize-a por questões de organização. No futuro, se você não fizer as coisas como recomenda-se que sejam feitas, ficará quase impossível dar manutenção ao seu código.

Um segundo problema de usar o método abaixo é que se o usuário estiver que os cookies desabilitados, existe uma chance real de sua aplicação não funcionar como esperado. Mas, já que as pessoas que desabilitam cookies são minoria e dado os motivos acima, vamos lá.

## Considerações inciais

Seu código em uma vulnerabilidade chamada SQL Injection e está usando uma função descontinuada do PHP, tudo isso ali na linha onde faz INSERT.

Como é outro assunto, não abordarei aqui. Apenas digo que deve ser corrigido antes de colocar o sistema em produção, do contrário, você terá dor de cabeça.

## Vamos lá

No ínicio dos seus arquivos upload.php e matricula.php, logo após a abertura da tag do PHP, inicie as sessions e deixe da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

    session_start();
```

Agora, estamos aptos a usar a variável super global `$_SESSION`. A variável `$_SESSION` é um `array`. Você deve armazenar seus dados nela em formato de array, nunca diretamente. Veja um exemplo:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    #certo
    $_SESSION['imageUrl'] = 'Aqui você pode colocar qualquer coisa'

    #errado
    $_SESSION = 'Essa é a maneira errada de usar sessions';
```

A mágica por trás das `sessions` é que diferente de uma variável comum, seja ela superglobal ou não, ela sempre estará disponível, inclusive em outras páginas da sua aplicação, inclusive após o usuário dar F5 ou até mesmo fechar a aba e voltar depois (fechar a aba do navegador é diferente de fechar o navegador).

Essa mágica funciona de uma forma lógica, afinal, não existe mágica. Para fins de desemcargo de conciência, vou explicar como isso acontece.

## Breve explicação sobre como funcionam as sessions no PHP

Quando você inicia uma session com o comando `session_start()`, o PHP por padrão cria um arquivo (isso pode ser alterado se desejar) e esse arquivo receberá um nome aleatório. Dentro desse arquivo, o PHP armazena uma `string` com todas as informações armazenadas na variável `$_SESSION`, assim, ao recarregar a página, ele vai atrás desse arquivo e trás os dados que estão nele de volta. Pra isso dar certo, ele cria um `cookie` no navegador do visitante e esse cookie armazena o ID da sessão, por isso, se o visitante estiver com os cookies desabilitados não irá funcionar. Com o ID da sessão, o PHP não gera outro ID, ele simplesmente vai atrás dos dados da sessão já existentes para aquele ID.

Claro que isso aqui é uma explicação bem básica e não aborda tudo que poderia ser abordado. Como eu disse, vale a pena pesquisar sobre o assunto. Inclusive, sessions são um recurso quase que obrigatório para sistemas que precisam que o usuário possa fazer login.

## Solução para o caso

```
<?php

session_start();

/* se enviar a foto, insere o nome da foto no banco de dados */
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $pasta . $nome_atual)) {
                $_SESSION['imageUrl'] = $pasta . $nome_atual;
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO fotos (foto) VALUES (".$nome_atual.")");
                echo "<img src='fotos/".$nome_atual."' id='previsualizar' class='img-responsive'>"; //imprime a foto na tela
                echo "'http://audiosonic.com.br/novo/fotos/".$nome_atual."'";
            } else {
                echo "Falha ao enviar";
            }
        } else {
            echo "A imagem deve ser de no máximo 1MB";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Somente são aceitos arquivos do tipo Imagem";
    }
} else {
    echo "Selecione uma imagem";
    exit;
}
```

Na página matricula.php, apenas use a variável da seguinte forma, quando for conveniente:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    echo "O caminho da imagem é {$_SESSION['imageUrl']}";
```

Lembrando que você não precisa obrigatóriamente colocar esse caminho em um input. Se não for obrigatório pro cliente visualizar o caminho, você pode deixar ele somente na variável $_SESSION e usá-lo apenas no PHP pra fazer o cadastro.

Dica: sempre utilize a documentação do PHP, lá eles possuem dicas de utilização de todos os recursos da linguagem, inclusive dicas sobre [sessions](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php).

Comment: não deu muito certo, porque quando eu abro o frame relativo à este upload, ele já mostra um nome de arquivo, antes mesmo de eu carregar. Me parece ser o arquivo anterior. Quando eu carrego a imagem, para que ela apareça pra mim em visualização, o código é o seguinte:

Comment: `<script src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#imagem').live('change',function(){
           $('#visualizar').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
           /* Efetua o Upload sem dar refresh na pagina */           $('#formulario').ajaxForm({
                                target:'#visualizar' // o callback será no elemento com o id #visualizar
                            }).submit();
       });
   })
</script>`

Comment: Esse último echo, eu coloquei de propósito, para ter o caminho completo da imagem: `echo "'http://audiosonic.com.br/novo/fotos/".$nome_atual."'";` Será que não é mais fácil "espelhar" esse `echo` na página de matrícula?

Comment: http://imgur.com/d6cAYeO - Aqui eu mostro o que está acontecendo

Comment: Você pode resolver isso dando um unset($_SESSION['imageUrl']); depois de usar o valor da variável na página matricula.php

Comment: Não está dando certo. Onde eu posso postar o código completo, para que possa ver?